# Show a list of objects in android

Tags: android, for-loop, foreach, iterator

I'm trying to show a whole list of objects but I only shows the last list.

my code that I use for travel, but it shows me only the last of the list.

Sorry for my bad english :(

Code:

```
if(!L.isEmpty()){
        for(Iterator<Bits> i = L.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            Bits item = i.next();
            imageBit.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(item.getbImage()));
            nameBit.setText(item.getbText());
            System.out.println(item);
        }


    }
```

Comment: I suppose the imageBit is just one ImageView so the bitmap of that image is overwritten at each loop with no delay and that's why you only see the last one.

Comment: Thank you, and if I wanted to go showing each separated by time (seconds), that could do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show all the images with some delay try this.

In your class create the following vars:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
private int currentPosition = 0;
```

And then call the following method to start showing the images in the onCreate, onResume or when you want it all to start:

```
showNextImage();
```

Ant the code for showNextImage should be something like:

```
private void showNextImage() {
    // loads the image at position currentPosition
    Bits item = L.get(currentPosition);
    imageBit.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(item.getbImage()));
    nameBit.setText(item.getbText());
    System.out.println(item);

    currentPosition++; // updates the current position
    if (L.size() > currentPosition) { // more images to show?
        // loads the next image after some delay
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                showNextImage();
            }
        }, 1000); // in millis, 1000 for one second delay
    }
}
```

I added some comments just to clarify. You can delete them.

It should work.

Comment: Thank you very much, helped me the example, because I now only need to do followed of showing the image  of the Bits showing the name of the same Bits and so on, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are setting new text values for nameBit TextView every iteration. Same for ImageView. So when the loop reaches its end, it assigns text value of last item name and same for the image. You should probably do next for the text:

```
if(!L.isEmpty()){
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  for(Iterator<Bits> i = L.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Bits item = i.next();
    imageBit
      .setImageBitmap(
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(item.getbImage())
      );
    builder.append(item.getbText()).append("\n");
  }
  String resultingText= builder.toString();
  nameBit.setText(resultingText);
  System.out.println(resultingText);
}
```

This will show all the text values in your TextView.
By the way, with this implementation in imageBit you'll see only the last image.
So i assume, that you are not properly choose architecture. Please refer to [ListView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) or [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html) documentation. Purpose of this views are to show list of objects, if you'll properly implement it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but and if I wanted to go showing each separated by time (seconds), that could do it? @Eugene Laminskiy

Comment: To show items separately (as a list) you should implement ListView or RecycleView.